# error en modelo ManyToMany

Tags: python, ajax, django-models

Tengo dos modelos con relación **ManyToMany** y quiero insertar integrantes pero al intentarlo me genera un error.

Lo que quiero lograr es **crear un integrante nuevo** que es *almacenado en el modelo Member*.
Lo que hago es tomar el **pk** desde la tabla que es mostrada y lo *asigno a la variable pk* para tener el proyecto, al final recojo todos los valores del formulario y creo un nuevo integrante, después lo que hago es salvar el integrante y le paso el pk al proyecto que se asigna, en ese momento me dice:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' reference before assignment.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def ajax_create_member(request):
    member_form = MemberForm()
    pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    global e
    e.append(pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        surnames = request.POST['surnames']
        category = request.POST['category']
        email = request.POST['email']
        CI = request.POST['CI']
        academic_year = request.POST['academic_year']
        form = MemberForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Este es el pk')
            print(e[0])
            project = Project.objects.get(pk=d[0])
            d = []
            member = Member.objects.create(
                name=name, surnames=surnames, category=category, email=email, CI=CI, academic_year=academic_year
            )
            project.member=member
            project.save()
            projects = Project.objects.all()
            data = {
                'msg': 'El integrante se ha guardado satisfactoriamente',
                'page': render_to_string('project/list_project.html', {'projects': projects}, request=request),
                'header': render_to_string('project/dinamic_project.html', request=request),
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data = {
            'page': render_to_string('project/member/add.html', {'form': member_form}, request=request)
        }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Y el Error  es el siguiente:

> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\Users\Edivaldo Gomes\PycharmProjects\science\applications\projects\views.py", line 423, in ajax_create_other_member return JsonResponse(data) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment [2019/01/25 14:00:15] HTTP POST /ciencia/project/member/other/add 500 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:56663]

Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Añade el error que te sale, el titulo de la pregunta modificala por algo mas corto y pon una descripción del tu problema, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: El error mostrado es : response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Edivaldo Gomes\PycharmProjects\science\applications\projects\views.py", line 423, in ajax_create_other_member
    return JsonResponse(data)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
[2019/01/25 14:00:15] HTTP POST /ciencia/project/member/other/add 500 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:56663]

Comment: Añade una intro de lo que quieres lograr,cual es la linea 423 que te marca?...etc, de esta manera no entiendo que sucede.

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es crear un integrante nuevo que es almacenado en el modelo Member,lo que hago es coger el pk desde la tabla que es mostrada y lo asigno a la variable pk para tener el proyecto, al final recojo todos los valores del formulario y creo un nuevo integrante, después lo que hago es salvar el integrante y le paso el pk al proyecto que se asigna. y me dice que UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data'  reference before assignment

Comment: Checa que tu   if form.is_valid(): te esta devolviendo false